# exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno

Tags: arduino-ide, exitstatus

I am using arduino IDE since a year with old version 1.5.8
After I updated the version of arduino (due to some errors in old version) I am getting this error even when I compile an empty default sketch:

```
C:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/bin/ar.exe: core\wiring_pulse.S.o: No such file or directory

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

I have tried many solutions on forum and stackoverflow 
Nothing has solved my error.

What should I do ???

ALso, I suspect NPAV antivirus which I installed in my laptop recently maybe causing the error, since the scan shows some arduino files as threats... 
But I am not sure if that is the issue. And as NPAV is a paid software I didn't remove it to see if the error goes. though i tried disabling NPAV which didn't help.

Comment: The first part of the path suggests that you're using Windows, but the second part of the path suggests that you're using Linux. I'd suggest uninstalling the Arduino IDE and re-installing it. This does not look to be related to your anti-virus.

Comment: I am using windows 10 and I have tried reinstalling arduino like 6-7 times with different versions.. NOT working

Comment: Niharinka Srivastav, are you getting the same error as Aniruddha?
If your error is different, can you post it?

Comment: The error I was getting is in my post! Aniruddha edited my post i suppose!... I solved my error.... was getting error as my anti virus NPAV (recently installled) was detecting some arduino files as threats.... thus removing NPAV solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue 
I was guessing it's the new antivirus issue...
Thus uninstalled it 
Working perfectly now